# Listar todos los archivos de una URL

Tags: python

Tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar.
Tengo una URL en la que hay distintas carpetas según el día del mes. Es decir, en el mes de enero tengo 31 carpetas con nombres: 01,02,03,...,31. Entonces, me ayudaron el foro para conseguir listar todas las carpetas y recogerlas en variables de esta forma:

```
url= https://www.web.es/enero/
    for i in range(1,32):
        if i<10:
            url_i.append(url+"0"+str(i)+"/")
        else:
            url_i.append(url+str(i)+"/")
```

Lo que pasa es que ahora a mí me gustaría recorrer esas urls y listar los archivos de texto que hay dentro para luego a su vez abrir cada archivo de texto.
Por ejemplo. Cuando i=1, con el código anterior obtendría: https://www.web.es/enero/01/
y en esa dirección tendré distintos ficheros con distintos nombres, por ejemplo: fichero1.txt, esteesotroarchivo.txt, archivo5.txt...
Entonces lo que me gustaría es con otro código obtener:
https://www.web.es/enero/01/fichero1.txt
https://www.web.es/enero/01/esteesotroarchivo.txt
etc.

He probado a usar:

```
requests.get(i,allow_redirects=True)
```

Donde i es la carpeta en la que tengo los archivos que quiero listar, pero a parte de que poner la variable i no me funciona, si la sustituyo por una url completa:

```
requests.get("https://www.web.es/enero/01/",allow_redirects=True)
```

Me ejecuta el código, pero me muestra todo lo que hay en la página: títulos, comentarios, etc. y yo solo querría los nombres de los archivos.

¿Cómo podría lograr esto?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes los nombres de los archivos que debería haber en cada carpeta? ¿Es una serie de nombres fijos que tú conoces, o quieres obtener esos nombres también del servidor? Si es lo segundo no puedes hacerlo, salvo que el HTML que te responde al pedir la URL de la carpeta incluya enlaces hacia todos los ficheros contenidos.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Los archivos de texto tienen este nombre: i*n.txt donde i puede ser 0 o 1 y n un numero de tres cifras. Por ejemplo 1*245.txt. Lo que pasa es que en cada carpeta no están todos y pueden no estar los mismos. Por ejemplo en la carpeta 01 puede que este el archivo 1*245.txt y en la carpeta 02 puede que estén los archivos 0*5.txt, 1*100.txt, 1*99.txt